# Moving rows in multiple columns into their own columns Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe about purchase data which i need to shift around to make it easy to analyse. So far it looks like:

'''

```
df = 

  | customers bid/offer price  volume
 0| 28        B         95     1200
 1| 1         O         78     6
 2| SOA       IFILL     May20  F
 3| 15        B         99     3
 4| 18        O         60     3
 5| 120       B         40     70
 6| FAL       TGAL      May20  F
```

In the example table above the rows in index 2 and 6 represent specific item data about the records above them so i need them to have pulled out of the current columns and move over to their own columns next their relevant records. So i need the dataframe ideally to looks like this:

'''

```
df =

 | customers bid/offer price volume shopCode itemCode date  Type
0| 28        B         95    1200   SOA      IFILL    May20 F
1| 1         O         78    6      SOA      IFILL    May20 F
2| 15        B         99    3      FAL      TGAL     May20 F
3| 18        O         60    3      FAL      TGAL     May20 F
4| 120       B         40    70     FAL      TGAL     May20 F
```

Comment: You could attempt to split the dataframe into two DFs based on the "price" column (if it contains a number or date). Then, using the index, you could search the second DF for the smallest index number that is higher than the row index from DF1 and use that to get the values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution working if data has first numeric rows splitted by one non numeric rows by `price` column:

```
#for correct default RangeIndex
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#test numeric rows
m = df['price'].str.isnumeric()
#join together with removed 1 from index for correct match
df1 = pd.concat([df[m], df[~m].rename(lambda x: x-1)], axis=1)
#set correct columns names
L = ['shopCode','itemCode','date','Type']
df1.columns = df.columns.tolist() + L
#back filling missing values
df1[L] = df1[L].bfill()
print (df1)
  customers bid/offer price volume shopCode itemCode   date Type
0        28         B    95   1200      SOA    IFILL  May20    F
1         1         O    78      6      SOA    IFILL  May20    F
3        15         B    99      3      FAL     TGAL  May20    F
4        18         O    60      3      FAL     TGAL  May20    F
5       120         B    40     70      FAL     TGAL  May20    F
```